# If $|f|$ can be integrated using Riemann integration, does that mean that $f$ can be integrated using Riemann integration?

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

If $|f|$ can be integrated using Riemann integration, does that mean that $f$ can be integrated using Riemann integration?

Also

If $f^{2}$ can be integrated using Riemann integration, does that mean that $f$ can be integrated using Riemann integration?

Are there any examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational, and $-1$ if $x$ is irrational. The functions $|f|$ and $f^2$ are Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, but $f$ is not.

Comment: @MrDi: Sorry, it was supposed to be $-1$.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=-1$ when $x$ is rational? With $(x)=0$ on rationals we havr$|f|=f^2=f$ which is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, What about if $(f+g)$ can be integrated using Riemann Integration does that mean that $g,f$ can be integrated using Riemann Integration?

Comment: We can use the $f$ of my answer, and let $g=-f$. Then $f+g$ is identically $0$, so integrable, but neither $f$ nor $g$ is integrable.

Answer (score 1):

Pick the function: $f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R \setminus Q}  \\
-1, & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases} $

It is easy to see, this function is discontinuous everywhere and hence not Riemann integrable on any intervall, upper and lower sum differ.

However$ |f(x)| = 1 \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}  $ and integrable sufficing your first question.